# PhantomJS-Node in a for Loop

Tags: multithreading, node.js, multiprocessing, screen-scraping, phantomjs

I am trying to implement a screen-scrape app that opens a URL in which one parameter changes, this is done in a for loop as such:

```
 var data=['100','101','102','103','104'];

   for(var indexA = 0 ; indexA < data.length ; indexA++){
     phantom.create({'port' : freeport}, function(ph) {
        ph.createPage(function(page) {
            page.open("http://..."+ data[indexB] + "...", function(status) {
               console.log("opened site: " + data[indexB], status); 
                 /*OLD*/ indexB++;
                   page.evaluate(function() { //Scrape the page and return an object
                        },function(result){
                        console.log(result.dataRequest); //Here is the problem
                                 }); /*NEW AND FIXED*/ indexB++
     }
```

At first the console logs this:

```
  opened site: 100 success
    opened site: 101 success
    opened site: 102 success
    opened site: 103 success
    opened site: 104 success
```

which is good.

the dataRequest is in the scraped HTML and corresponds to the index in the array. So in page 101 I scrape and retrieve '101' and put in the result.
However when I console log the result.dataRequest I get:

```
100 
101 
102 
102 
102
```

My theory:
Something to do with multi-processing problem. I don't understand when exactly is the new phantomJS child process being created, and when its being deleted. Should I put some kind of mutex (JS version of a mutex..) around the result callback? 
This is causing a problem because I want to insert the result in to a DB , and when I check my DB I see duplicates of the same results.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imo, the problem is that js is asynchronous. it's look like you're loop is faster to process than phantomjs create method.

you can't determine how asynchronous method will run (regarding calls order and stuff)
i mean mostly all the time, in your example, you cannot be sure the phantom.create order will happend after the previous indexB++,

apparently in your logs, it works fine for 100 101 102, but a the fourth loop, you create the phantom instance then you start a new loop BUT, the step "indexB++;" didn't happend yet. so you do one more time a step loop with the same indexB....

tl,dr : 
in your case this is what happends :

```
create.phantom for 100
100++
create.phantom for 101
101++
create.phantom for 102
create.phantom for 102
create.phantom for 102
102++
103++
104++
```

what you might use is https://github.com/caolan/async to handle the asynchronous workflow.

Comment: I changed the location of indexB++ to the end of pageOpen and not inside its callback. This worked!

Answer (score 3):

Asynchronous methods inside of loops are always tricky. I've written an alternative for [phantomjs-node](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node) called [phridge](https://github.com/peerigon/phridge). Instead of turning all function calls and assignments into async operations it just executes the whole function inside PhantomJS.

Instead of

```
var data = ['100','101','102','103','104'];

for(var indexA = 0; indexA < data.length; indexA++){
    phantom.create({'port' : freeport}, function(ph) {
        ph.createPage(function(page) {
             page.open("http://..."+ data[indexB] + "...", function(status) {
                console.log("opened site: " + data[indexB], status); 
                page.evaluate(function() {
                    //Scrape the page and return an object
                }, function (result) {
                    console.log(result.dataRequest); //Here is the problem
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

you could write (using [when.js](https://github.com/cujojs/when))

```
// spawn one phantomjs process
phridge.spawn()
    .then(function (phantom) {
        // open a new page for every provided url
        return when.map(['100','101','102','103','104'], function (data) {
            return phantom.openPage("http://..." + data + "...");
        });
    })
    .then(function (pages) {
        // scrape each page
        return when.map(pages, function (page) {
            return page.run(function () {
                // this function runs inside PhantomJS
                return this.evaluate(function () {
                    // scrape the site and return results
                    return result;
                });
            });
        });
    })
    .then(function (results) {
        // process results
    });
```